# figuring it out the source of an error on production

Tags: angular

I am having a bit of headache. the app works well in dev mode. And after i do build --prod and serve the files with my local http server, it also works. But in my production server, I get this error and the app does not load:

```
main.8ec24b26ac1406485605.bundle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'v4' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.8ec24b26ac1406485605.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.Wa/L (main.8ec24b26ac1406485605.bundle.js:1)
    at t (inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.x35b (main.8ec24b26ac1406485605.bundle.js:1)
    at t (inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.0 (main.8ec24b26ac1406485605.bundle.js:1)
    at t (inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js:1)
    at window.webpackJsonp (inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js:1)
    at main.8ec24b26ac1406485605.bundle.js:1
```

Is there a way to see the source of the error?

Comment: You can build in production mode without minifying. Your headache will go away (maybe)

Comment: Try `ng build --prod --optimization=false`

Comment: Thanks guys. Funny, with false, it builds well and no error in the app. Guess I will live with the bigger bundle size app

Comment: Uhm that wasn't meant to a solution